# How can i remove an appended element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom-manipulation

I'm doing an exercise from javascriptissexy.com, the exercise is to build a quizzer. i'm trying to show a question based on the variable page value, question are stored in array object, when a the next button is clicked the page variable is incremented by 1 and the next question is shown with its choices.

What I want to do is after the next button click, remove the previous appended question and its choices.. how can i do this?

```
function createQuiz(crPage) {
    textNode = Allquestions[indexController].question;
    switch (crPage) {
        case 0:
            $("legend").append(textNode);
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 1:
            $("legend").append(textNode);
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 2:
            $("legend").append(textNode);
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 3:
            $("legend").append(textNode);
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 4:
            $("legend").append(textNode);
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 5:
            $("legend").append(textNode);
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 6:
            $("legend").append(textNode);
            appendChoices()
            break;

        default:
            // code

    }
}


function appendChoices() {
    for (var i = 0; i < Allquestions[indexController].choices.length; i++) {
            console.log(Allquestions[indexController].choices[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you use jQuery but; using jQuery empty() function you can easily remove previously added question like:

```
$('legend').empty();
```

You can find more information here: [jQuery API empty() function](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Answer (score 2):

Well instead of using `.append()` each time, you can use **[`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)** over `$("legend").children()`.

For example the code in each case will look like this:

```
$("legend").children().replaceWith(textNode);
appendChoices()
break;
```

It will replace the `$("legend")` content in each case.

**Edit:**

Or best approach would be to use **[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** method like this:

```
$("legend").html(textNode);
appendChoices()
break;
```

**Note:**

I see that you are doing the same thing in each case, by using the same statements, what's the purpose of the `switch` block?

Comment: is this good rather than using the suggested empty() but wrap inside a function? so i can call the function in each case? like this
`function appendQuestion(){
                $('legend').empty()
            .append(textNode);
}`

Comment: @Jcan There's no good here, they are just two ways of doing things, but I think the best would be to use `.html()` method, see my Edit.